# After how many days google update the map details?

Tags: google-places-api

Actually I am using the Google Places API for web application. I want address and phone number for search string. If I search 'checkpoint company', I got the place details but in that the phone numbers are old. It contains old data.

So my question is after how many days Google map updates the place details ?

Comment: have you logged into the Google Places account and updated the details?

Comment: @martincarlin87 No, I am just using the Goggle place details, I have not added any place details

Comment: I have no idea where Google gets the details from originally but if you want to update the business details then the best way is to probably create a Places account to verify that it's your business and update the details that way.